# Estimated Row Height Not Working on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am running iOS 8 and trying to set the estimated row height but it is not producing the correct result.

In viewDidLoad I have these lines:

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

In my heightForRowAtIndexPath I have the following:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

UITableViewAutomaticDimension always return -1.

Also, when I scroll the tableview all the text from previous cells gets jumbled together for some reason.

Comment: Do you have constraints set up correctly in your cell?

Comment: Most probably not! There are so many constraints I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: You can never get the real value of your cell only in cellWillDisplay method

Comment: OK - first, if you are using auto-sizing cells, you don't need to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Second, start simple... get it to work with correct constraints for *one* element in your cell, then add another element and adjust the constraints. When that works, add another element. Keep going until you have all the elements / subviews in your cell set up correctly.